# How to optimise DB schema for a meal planner app?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I am designing a DB schema for a meal planning application. Each meal plan consists of blocks (2 months of diet, 2 months of bulking), each block of meals for the day, each meal of the day of foods.

I made a normalized DB schema, however if I wanted to fetch a whole meal plan with it's analysis, the query would go through more than 6 different tables, which could really slow the application in the future. But I don't see a way to do it differently. To get the whole meal plan, it would have to through `MealProgram` > `MealProgramBlock` > `DayMeal` > `DayMealFood` > `FoodOnDayMealFood` > `Food` > `FoodNutrient` > `Nutrient`.

I know that NoSQL solution could be a fit for this use case, but that's a no-go in case I need to update a specific nutrient or food, I don't want to update all the existing records.

```
Table User {
  id varchar [primary key]
}

Table Food {
  id varchar [primary key]
  name String
}

Table FoodNutrient {
  foodId varchar [ref: > Food.id]
  nutrientId varchar [ref: > Nutrient.id]
  amount integer
}

Table Nutrient {
  id varchar [primary key]
  name varchar
  unitName String
}

Table MealProgram {
  id varchar [primary key]
  name varchar
  authorId varchar [ref: > User.id]
  customerId varchar [ref: > User.id]
}

Table MealProgramBlock {
  id varchar [primary key]
  name varchar
  programId varchar [ref: > MealProgram.id]
}

Table DayMeal {
  id varchar [primary key]
  blockId varchar [ref: > MealProgramBlock.id]
  name varchar
  day integer
  time varchar
}

Table DayMealFood {
  id varchar [primary key]
  dayMealId varchar [ref: > DayMeal.id]
}

Table FoodOnDayMealFood {
  id varchar [primary key]
  dayMealFoodId varchar [ref: > DayMealFood.id]
  foodId varchar [ref: > Food.id]
  weight integer
  unit varchar
}
```

[image]

Comment: A varchar as id is not common, usually it's an integer/biginteger or a UUID. Time sounds like "time" to me, not "varchar". So please check your data types: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens I use Prisma as an ORM, and it uses CUID for IDs, therefore varchar. Didn't know it has time, only datetime, thanks

Comment: Do you really think you must have a CUID? A bigint gives you 9223372036854775807 unique values, that should be enough for the entire world population for the next couple of decades. And makes your database much faster and leaner.

Comment: Even though I see your point, in the question I meant to improve the whole structure.

Comment: Hard to help you, we hardly know anything about your requirements. And without much context, no (unique) constraints and varchar all over the place, you most likely have a challenge to get it right. About the varchar fields, is this valid content for these columns? "what about this piece of content that could go anywhere" And would it be valid to create a million records with this this content? And you're talking about a four month (2x2) diet, but it has no start nor end. There is no check either if you have any diet at all, you can't check for gaps, how many meals a day, in what order, etc

Comment: It's good to be cognizant of potential future performance issues related to design decisions; however, the initial design should not have unnecessary complications added to address issues that don't yet exist. Joining though six tables, assuming appropriate indexes, is probably not going to be unacceptably slow. As @FrankHeikens has mentioned, there are several issues with the model at this stage. Create a model that adequately addresses the problem domain. Don't intentionally create a non-performant design, but avoid premature optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data-model so used strongly depends on  what kind of  database solution is hosting that  data . In your case its Postgres and these suggestions are targeted so . If e.g. the database was a MPP one like Teradata it'd be totally different. Having said that here are some pointers .Can grab  any that would work for you.

- consolidate the `DayMealFood` and `FoodOnDayMealFood` tables into a single `Meal` table. This would allow you to store all of the information about a meal in a single place, and it would reduce the number of joins you need to perform when fetching a meal plan.
- Add a `meal_type` column to the Meal table. This would allow you to distinguish between different types of meals, such as breakfast, lunch, dinner, and snacks. This information could be used to generate reports and insights about user meal patterns.
- Add  a `meal_plan_id` column to the `Meal table`. This would allow you to associate meals with meal plans, and it would make it easier to fetch all of the meals in a particular meal plan.
- Add a `created_at` and `updated_at` column to all of the tables in your data model. This would allow you to track changes to the data over time
- `composite primary key` for the `DayMealFood table`. Single id value is not very useful for querying the table e.g.  to find all of the meals that contain a particular food, need a  join  of  DayMealFood table &  Food table. `composite primary key`  ( `dayMealId` and `foodId` columns) would allow you to query the table by day meal or by food without having to join 2 tables.
- `materialized view` for the `MealPlan`. improves performance by `caching` frequently used data  When a user requests a meal plan, the application could first check to see if the meal plan is in the `materialized view`. If the meal plan is in the materialized view, the application can simply return the data from the materialized view
- use a `caching layer` to store the data from the `DayMealFood` table. This would allow the application to fetch data from the caching layer instead of the database. This would significantly improve the performance of the application when users request meal plans

Answer (score 0):

From a comment of yours in the chat we see you're using Prisma. Unfortunately Prisma does **not do JOINs** yet. So it actually performs **multiple SQL queries** on your normalized tables where a bunch of JOINs in a single query would usually not be a performance issue at all - they actually are the foundation of SQL databases.

So, the choice of technology is the culprit here. See also: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5184

If you can't find an alternative technology suitable for you and you have to go with Prisma, a denormalization could be an approach.

Updating multiple records for a change of `nutrient` or `food` may feel wrong in the world of RDBMs but a technology not even capable of doing JOINs also is.

An alternative could be:

Choose another ORM (if you really need one) that is able to perform JOINs, like [sequelize](https://sequelize.org) or [knex](https://knexjs.org)

A more radical alternative could be:

Choose a tool for defining your DDL (database schema) and running migrations, like [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) and write your SQL statements vanilla using the [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) client lib.